# setting up cron Job from bash is giving errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am trying to set up a cron Job in a remote server using a bash script.The command is as follows:

```
ssh $NODE_USER@$NODE_HOST "cat <(crontab -l) <(echo "33 03 * * 0-6 $Scripts_dir/runStaticHTML.sh -c $Scripts_dir/staticHTML.conf") | crontab - "
```

When I execute this command inside the server directly,it runs fine.But when I run though this Bash ,it is giving the following error

```
copysetup.sh: command substitution: line 68: syntax error near unexpected token `('
copysetup.sh: command substitution: line 68: `cat <(crontab -l) < (echo "33 03 * * 0-6 $Scripts_dir/runStaticHTML.sh -c $Scripts_dir/staticHTML.conf") | crontab - '
```

and it will end up logging into the remote server.

When I exit out of the server,then it gives the following error.
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Comment: It looks like the `ssh` server is running the script undef `sh`, not `bash`, so process substitution with `<(...)` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

The `ssh` server is running the command using `sh`, not `bash`, so it doesn't understand `<(command)` (this is a bash extension).

You don't need to use process substitution for this. Try:

```
ssh $NODE_USER@$NODE_HOST "(crontab -l; echo '33 03 * * 0-6  $Scripts_dir/runStaticHTML.sh -c $Scripts_dir/staticHTML.conf') | crontab -"
```

Note also that the variable `$Scripts_dir` is expanded on the local machine, not the server.

Comment: Hi Barmar.Thanks for the suggestions.I have tried the above command.It is still the same behavior.when I run the script it does ssh and log into the server and from there it is not proceeding.Is there any other way to set up the cron job from the sh script.

Comment: I made a mistake, you can't escape double quotes inside strings. I changed them to single quotes.

Comment: Hmm, I take that back. It's single quotes that don't allow escaping, double quotes do. I'm not sure why it was failing for you. But try the new version anyway.